# Are maximalist shoes like Hoka good for running?

Tags: long-distance-running, running-shoes, barefoot, hip, feet

When I was running with low shoes (close to barefoot), I was getting a lot of injuries in my feet, but these injuries were minor; after just 3 days of recovering, my feet were much stronger. After a couple of months, I decided to try a pair of shoes with a lot of cushion but then, after just a month, I had a major pain in my hip. Now, I want to come back to my low shoes, but I would like to know if someone has used this type of shoes, the [maximalism](http://running.competitor.com/2013/08/shoes-and-gear/2014-running-trend-oversized-shoes_79859) of Hoka One One. They look very big. Can this type of shoes really be good for long distance running on hard surfaces?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, people use this shoe: http://blogs.militarytimes.com/pt365/2013/06/11/review-hoka-one-ones-stinson-trail-shoes-look-like-clown-shoes-but-laugh-at-punishing-terrain/

Sara Davidson ran the Laurel Highlands 70-miler in them.

In total, she has run about 400 miles in them and they're starting to need replacement. So, they didn't make it to the 800 miles claimed by the manufacturer.

Comment: A lot of older triathletes are starting to adopt them as well, as it really works well with their gaits and for cushioning. I know Dan Empfield (creator of slowtwitch.com and the original inventor of the triathlon geometry time trial frame with Quintana Roo) swears by them.